# Verilog - Nonblocking statement confusion

Tags: verilog

I always thought that with non-blocking statements, that they all occur in parallel at the end of the always block.

But consider this example I found:

https://www.nandland.com/articles/blocking-nonblocking-verilog.html

```
always @(posedge i_clock)
begin
  r_Test_1 <= 1'b1;
  r_Test_2 <= r_Test_1;
  r_Test_3 <= r_Test_2;
end
```

It says that "The always block in the Verilog code above uses the Nonblocking Assignment, which means that it will take 3 clock cycles for the value 1 to propagate from r_Test_1 to r_Test_3."

That doesn't make any sense. If it takes 3 clock cycles for the value to propagate then surely it's happening in series too and not in parallel?

Comment: Okay. I just don't get why each statement would take one clock cycle to run even though we have specified no delay. I mean, shouldn't it all happen at once at the end? r_test_3 takes on value from r_test_2 and r_test_2 takes on r_test_1 and r_test_1 takes on 1'b1. All of that should take one clock cycle.

Comment: Oh. I get it now. It takes one clock cycle for it to propogate once and hence 3 clock cycles to get to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nonblocking statements do run in parallel every time the always block is run. However, each assignment uses the previous value of the right hand side when assigning. If we simulate the design, we can see this behavior:

[image]

Initially, all of the signals have a value of 0, however on the first rising edge `r_Test_1` takes on a value of 1, while the other two registers stay 0. This is because `r_Test_2` is assigned the value of `r_Test_1` just *before* the clock edge, and `r_Test_1` is 0 just before the rising edge.

A similar behavior happens on the second rising edge, this time with `r_Test_2` and `r_Test_3`. `r_Test_2` becomes 1 on the second rising edge because this time `r_Test_1` had a value of 1 just before the clock edge, but because `r_Test_2` was still 0 just before this edge, `r_Test_3` remains 0.

Let's contrast this with the behavior of this code:

```
always @(posedge i_clock)
begin
    r_Test_1 = 1'b1;
    r_Test_2 = r_Test_1;
    r_Test_3 = r_Test_2;
end
```

[image]

Because I've used blocking assignments here, each register is assigned the value immediately instead of the assignment being deferred until the end of the always block. Because of this, when `r_Test_2` is being assigned, `r_Test_1` already has a value of 1, and likewise with `r_Test_3` and `r_Test_2`, so all 3 signals take a value of 1 on the first cycle.

Now that I am using blocking assignments, order has become important. So if I rearrange the code to look like this:

```
always @(posedge i_clock)
begin
    r_Test_1 = 1'b1;
    r_Test_3 = r_Test_2;
    r_Test_2 = r_Test_1;
end
```

I then get a different result from the second simulation: 
[image]

Challenge: why is this so?

Full test bench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps
module test;
    reg i_clock = 0;

    reg r_Test_1 = 0;
    reg r_Test_2 = 0;
    reg r_Test_3 = 0;

    initial begin
        $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
        $dumpvars;
        #100 $finish;
    end

    always #5 i_clock <= ~i_clock;

    always @(posedge i_clock)
    begin
        r_Test_1 <= 1'b1;
        r_Test_2 <= r_Test_1;
        r_Test_3 <= r_Test_2;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: In my test bench I initialized them to 0, as I felt that `X` would have been more confusing without adding any value to the explanation.

Comment: Hmm. Right so - r_Test_1 gets 1'b1 at the first pos edge and r_Test_3 is procedurally assigned a value of what r_Test_2 has at that time - which is a unknown value - but it's assigned a zero for some reason??? Shouldn't it be a unknown value??And then r_Test_2 gets the 1'b1 value from r_Test_1. Then at the second pos-edge, r_Test_3 takes on the 1'b1 from r_Test_2.

Comment: Just saw your comment that you initialized them as 0. Perfect. I think I get it now. Thank you so much for the simulation and detailed explanation!

Comment: Out of curiosity - are you using Icarus Verilog and GTKWave?

Comment: Iverilog and scansion as I'm using a mac.

Comment: Ah. Mac I see. Thanks.